# I am trying to build a tiktoc clone. Every functionality works except for the like button that prompts the error below

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02jj8.png)

Please help

I have tried to make it null aware but the same error keeps coming up

Comment: Don't post images of code or errors. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting a `!` on a value without checking if it's null, change your `if` condition with:

```
if (doc.data != null && (doc.data()! as dynamic)['likes']?.contains(uid)) {
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you but i noticed that i used different variable names for firebase and code. But i've been able to resolve the issue